# Concat n files and output on screen and file

Tags: c, binaryfiles

I am writing a program that takes integer n and n files and combines the file and outputs it on the screen and the file "output.txt". I wrote this code for it but it neither prints it on the screen nor does it write on the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
size_t file_size(FILE *f){
        fseek(f,0,SEEK_END);
        size_t size = ftell(f);
        fseek(f,0,SEEK_SET);
        return size;
}

void copy(FILE *src, FILE *out){
        unsigned char buffer[64];
        size_t size = file_size(src);
        fseek(src,0,SEEK_SET);
        while(fread(buffer,sizeof(buffer),1,src) && size > 0){
                if (size < 64){
                        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer),size,out);
                        printf("%s",buffer);
                        size = 0;
                }
                else{
                        fwrite(buffer,sizeof(buffer),64,out);
                        size = size - 64;
                        printf("%s",buffer);
                }
        }
        printf("\n");
}

int main(){
        int num;
        char file[100];
        scanf("%d",&num);
        getchar();
        FILE *out;
        out = fopen("output.txt","w");
        if (out == NULL){
                exit(1);
        }
        for (int i=0;i<num;i++){
                scanf("%s",file);
                getchar();
                FILE *src;
                src = fopen(file,"rb");
                if (src == NULL){
                        exit(1);
                }
                copy(src,out);
                fwrite("\n",1,1,out);
                fclose(src);
        }
        fclose(out);
}
```

Can you help me figure out what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: When you run your program, does it do anything, or does it just sit there doing (apparently) nothing?  It is blocked on `getchar()`, waiting for input.

Comment: I can input integer and file names but it does not print anything. The program ends without printing

Comment: Or, perhaps `fopen` failed to open the output file and the program terminates without printing an error message, (you should add an error message!)

Comment: `fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer),size,out);` is trying to output much more data than was input by `fread`. You should really swap the `size` and `count` arguments around in `fread` and collect the function return value which will be the number of items (now bytes) actually read. You then write that number of bytes to the output. You don't need to find the file size first, just loop until no bytes were read. Note too that `printf("%s",buffer);` is expecting to be given a NULL terminated string but if the input is a text file it probably isn't. If a text file think about using `fgets` in a loop.